# Where are Google Play services jar files on Windows?

Tags: java, android, windows

I installed VS2015 with Android support on Windows 10. If I run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe", it shows that Google Play services samples are in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\" , but I cannot figure out where Google Play services themself are and what is the path to their jar files? (if they have jar files).

I am getting "package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist" Java compiler error while compiling some QT project containing some Java code and trying figure out either the package does not exist on my machine at all or QT Creator is not configured properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It located at extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms
You can extract .aar to see .jar file

Comment: I do not have m2repository folder in extras/google, I have only google_play_services and market_licensing

Comment: But I have "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\" folder that contain only 'android' but not 'google'